# Проблемы с curl https://api.twitter.com

Tags: curl, ssl, openssl

Запрос с сервера заканчивается ошибкой. С остальными сайтами проблем нет, только с твиттером. Гугление данной ошибки ничем не помогло

```
curl -v https://api.twitter.com
*   Trying 104.244.42.130:443...
* Connected to api.twitter.com (104.244.42.130) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, decode error (562):
* error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
```

curl 7.81.0

OpenSSL 3.0.2

Comment: Вероятно, вы находитесь в стране, в которой твиттер заблокирован

Comment: @andreymal Об этом мы тоже думали. Но с Фейсбуком проблем нет, а он тоже заблокирован

Comment: @andreymal Да и с сервера твиттер пингуется беспроблем

Comment: @Dinario то, что сервер твиттера пингуется, не означает, что на периметре не стоит редиректор для HTTPS. Попробуйте сделать запрос на HTTP  `curl -v http://api.twitter.com/`. Если твиттер не блокирован, то в ответе должно быть вроде `< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` и `< location: https://api.twitter.com/`

Comment: @PakUula Да, спасибо. Действительно это так. Через прокси все заработало. Странно, что фейсбук работает и без прокси.